# Form onsubmit="" with confirm window not working

Tags: php, html, forms, onsubmit

On my site, it should be possible to delete specific data from the database, but you can only delete the data you created. If you look at some data, my php code checks, if the account your logged in with is the "creator-account" of the data. If yes, it will show you a button to delete the data.

```
if ($_SESSION['userID'] == $creatorID) {
  echo
    '<form onsubmit="return confirm("Do you really want to delete this entry?");" class="c-inline" action="delete.php" method="post">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value ="'. $id .'"/>
      <button id="btnDelete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button" title="Eintrag löschen">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Löschen
      </button>
    </form>';
}
```

The Problem is, when you press the button, it should ask you if you really want to delete the data, but it doesn't. The message doesn't show up and I instantly get redirected to `delete.php`.

Any ideas why my `onsubmit=""` gets ignored?

Comment: Quotes, quotes, quotes. And for large blocks of HTML, you can step out of PHP, `?><html here><?php`. But a solution for you, use `onsubmit="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this entry?\');"`

Comment: your "security" doesnt work at all. You can bruteforce any id in the frondend and your data is gone

Comment: @user2659982 Is there any simple way to prevent this? This is a school project and we never learned something about that...

Comment: Depends all on how you generate the IDs, but most importantly that you **validate** the user inside `delete.php` as well.

Comment: Yes, i will do that for sure. And if i get some time, i will also read about the bruteforce attack!

Comment: As long as you properly validate the user in all relevant files (e.g. `delete.php`), so that they can only deal with files and IDs they are allowed to work on, it can't be bruteforced. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using the quotes a bit wrong. Using double-quotes for the `onsubmit` attribute, and the function inside, that breaks the quotes. So your `onsubmit` only sees `return confirm(` (because after that comes a quote of the same kind which you opened that attribute with). Replace the inner doublequotes with singlequotes; but they have to be escaped (because you `echo` this string).

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['userID'] == $creatorID) {
  echo
    '<form onsubmit="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this entry?\');" class="c-inline" action="delete.php" method="post">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value ="'. $id .'"/>
      <button id="btnDelete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button" title="Eintrag löschen">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Löschen
      </button>
    </form>';
}
```

A more readable alternative would be to exit PHP mode, and output it as pure HTML. This way you can use singlequotes without having to escape them.

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['userID'] == $creatorID) {
  ?>
  <form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this entry?');" class="c-inline" action="delete.php" method="post">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value ="<?= $id ?>"/>
      <button id="btnDelete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button" title="Eintrag löschen">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Löschen
      </button>
    </form>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Happy to have been of assistance! Note that if you went with the second solution, and if you're on a PHP version *earlier* than 5.4, you will need short opening tags, for the `<?=` to work.